# RS-232 Parity Check in Windows Mobile 6.1

Tags: serial-port, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.1

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202767.aspx), the `fParity` member of `DCB` structure is boolean.

> If this member is set to TRUE, parity checking is performed, and
>   errors are reported

So, how can I set `even` or `odd` parity checking when my application opens the serial port?

PS: I'm writing a minimalistic terminal application for Windows Mobile 6.1 using a FT232RL chip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, fParity enables parity checking.  Also note the **Parity** field, a BYTE.  It selects the *kind* of parity checking you want.  Five options but you'd typically choose EVENPARITY or ODDPARITY.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. 0 equals `FALSE`, and all other values equal `TRUE`. Right? I ask this because I come from a Pascal background.

Comment: It is a bit field, only 0 and 1 are legal values.  FALSE and TRUE happen to be 0 and 1.

Comment: if it is a bit field, then how can it differentiate between `EVENPARITY` and `ODDPARITY`?

Comment: No.  fParity is a bit field.  Parity is a BYTE.  This seems to keep hinging on you not seeing the **two** fields in the structure that determines how parity is configured.